# Reorder Collection View Cells buggy

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, batman.js

I'm able to get the cells to move around but it's buggy. When you move them around the pictures change and they don't stay where you move them. When you scroll down and scroll back, they move back.

```
//
//  CollectionViewController.swift
//  1.7 Task: Displaying Sets of Data: Collection View
//
//  Created by Eric Andersen on 3/26/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Eric Andersen. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var batmanDataItems = [DataItem]()
    var jokerDataItems = [DataItem]()
    var allItems = [[DataItem]]()

    var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        for i in 1...29 {
            if i > 0 {
                batmanDataItems.append(DataItem(title: "Title #\(i)", kind: Kind.Batman, imageName: "bat\(i).jpg"))

            } else {
                batmanDataItems.append(DataItem(title: "Title #0\(i)", kind: Kind.Batman, imageName: "bat0\(i).jpg"))
            }
        }

        for i in 1...8 {
            if i > 0 {
                jokerDataItems.append(DataItem(title: "Another Title #\(i)", kind: Kind.Joker, imageName: "jok\(i).jpg"))
            } else {
                jokerDataItems.append(DataItem(title: "Another Title #0\(i)", kind: Kind.Joker, imageName: "jok0\(i).jpg"))
            }
        }

        allItems.append(batmanDataItems)
        allItems.append(jokerDataItems)

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let width = collectionView!.frame.width / 3
        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)

        longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
        collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allItems[section].count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! DataItemCell
        let dataItem = allItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
        cell.dataItem = dataItem

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", for: indexPath) as! DataItemHeader
        var title = ""
        if let kind = Kind(rawValue: indexPath.section) {
            title = kind.description()
        }
        sectionHeader.title = title

        return sectionHeader
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // print("Starting Index: \(sourceIndexPath.item)")
        // print("Ending Index: \(destinationIndexPath.item)")
    }
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate


    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }



    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        allItems[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        }) { (finished) in
            self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: (self.collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems)!)
        }

    }

    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch(gesture.state) {

        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            collectionView?.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        case .changed:
            collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
        case .ended:
            collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView?.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }



}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIVd8.jpg)

I'm new. I know this is easy but I'm still getting the hang of this. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: In `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)` you need to move the data in your array to match the row that has been moved.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Moving the row only updates the screen, but it doesn't change your model (the array that supplies the data to your collectionView).  Then when cells go off screen and back on, they are loaded from your array which hasn't changed, which is why the cells go back to where they were.

You need to override `func collectionView(_:moveItemAt:to:)` and update your data array to reflect the row that was moved.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Remove the source item from the array and store it in item
    let item = allItems[sourceIndexPath.section].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)

    // insert the item into the destination location
    allItems[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.item)

}
```

Comment: saved my time. wasted hours in debugging thanks a lot